# How do I access the content of multiple <div> tags with HTMLAgilityPack?

Tags: c#, html, wpf, html-agility-pack

I am unable to find the documentation for the `HTMLAgilityPack` on the codeplex website. Currently what I want to do is access a div on the Amazon website, and scrape text information for use in a WPF application.

```
var getWeb = new HtmlWeb();                     
var doc = getWeb.Load(uri);
HtmlNode ourNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id = 'zg_centerListWrapper']");
```

This div contains about 12 other divs, each one is an item in the `best sellers` category.

In order to access the properties of each one would appear to be painstaking (and I'm also not entirely sure how I'd do it on first glance). So should I instead use `DocumentNode.SelectNodes()`? And how would I implement it? Also I find it hard to believe that after such a time there isn't documentation for the `HTMLAgilityPack`... Maybe I'm looking in the wrong places because youtube seems to be my best source at the moment.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, parameter of  `SelectNodes()` and `SelectSingleNode()` is an **xpath expression**, xpath version 1.0 to be precise (see [xpath 1.0 spec here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/)).

XPath is another technology with it's own specification, documentation, and discussion. You can generally search for xpath tutorials or articles instead of HtmlAgilityPack (HAP) specifics, to have a better idea of what kind of expression should you pass to HAP to get particular HTML elements.

For the sake of example, assume that your HTML looks like this :

```
<div id="zg_centerListWrapper">
    <div>I want this</div>
    <div>..and this</div>
    <div>..and this one too</div>
</div>
```

see that `div`s you're interested in are *direct children* of the `div[@id = 'zg_centerListWrapper']`, then you can use the following xpath to get them :

```
var xpath = "//div[@id = 'zg_centerListWrapper']/div";
HtmlNodeCollection ourNodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(xpath);
```

Comment: Thank you, but how would I start accessing/using the children of that div. Would I have to just use .SelectSingleNode on each - making this initial process where I try and use the children of 'zg_centerListWrapper' pointless? I'm sorry to bother you like this, I wouldn't if there was documentation.

Comment: you can loop through the result : `foreach(HtmlNode node in outNodes){//do sth with each node}`

Comment: HAP's `HtmlDocument` designed in the very similar way with [`XmlDocument`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you can reference the latter for the first, works in many cases, only need a little adjustment in the syntax (f.e replace `Xml` with `Html`, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DocumentNode.Descendants("div")` and then something like

```
.Where(div => div.Attributes.Contains("class") && div.Attributes["class"].Value.Contains("best category"))
```

But yeah, documentation would certainly help..